# limit pull count and branch for github repo to be < n

Tags: github

I want to prevent any new pull counts and/or new branches from being created in case it crosses a threshold (e.g. n=10).
Should be enabled only if the present count goes below < 10

Answer (score 0):

GitHub doesn't offer this functionality.  A repository can contain arbitrary numbers of branches and pull requests.

If you're using GitHub Enterprise Server, you can do this with a pre-receive hook, but those are not available on github.com.

It's likely that you actually want to do something other than limit the number of branches and pull requests and that this is a way to achieve some other goal.  If you ask a new question about how to achieve that goal, you may get solutions to that problem that are possible.